# Pandas sometimes writes empty or damaged files

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas

I've been using pandas for a while and I think it is a great tool. I made a program to generate some excel files from some data collected by the user. The final user have been testing and using it for 6 months; it never failled till yesterday, when it generated a dagamaged excel file. When I opened it with a text editor, it was totally blank. The code to generate this file is this:

```
        escritor = pandas.ExcelWriter(direccion, engine='xlsxwriter')
        listaTotal.to_excel(escritor, index = False)
        escritor.save()
```

and:

```
        escritor = pandas.ExcelWriter(direccion + '.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
        self.listaFact.to_excel(escritor, index = False, startrow = 1, startcol = 0, sheet_name = 'Hoja1')
        escritor.save()
```

The second code fragment also uses some format options for the 'xlsxwriter', an example here:

```
        format = workbook.add_format()
        format.set_font_size(9)
        format.set_font_name('Sans Serif 12cpi')
        format.set_border()
        format.set_text_wrap()
```

This error happened twice; about 1 month ago and yesterday. I can't duplicate the error, I don't know what happened. And also the traceback is here, it shows the problem when the program reads the file, but this file was generated by the code posted before:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\WINNER\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PythonApplication4\PythonApplication4\PythonApplication4.py", line 792, in botonGenerarPedido
    self.generarPedido()
  File "C:\Users\WINNER\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PythonApplication4\PythonApplication4\PythonApplication4.py", line 904, in generarPedido
    self.generarVentasDia()
  File "C:\Users\WINNER\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PythonApplication4\PythonApplication4\PythonApplication4.py", line 927, in generarVentasDia
    listaTotal = pandas.io.excel.read_excel(direccion)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 151, in read_excel
    return ExcelFile(io, engine=engine).parse(sheetname=sheetname, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 188, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 435, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 91, in open_workbook_xls
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1230, in getbof
    bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1224, in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Depending on how you call python, it can sometimes shut down too quickly to flush files that have not been closed. Close all files after you write to them, and see if it fixes the problem

Comment: Are you saying pandas wrote the line of null bytes to the file?

Comment: @alexis The files use to be closed, in the case some of them are opened, the error is different, it is 'IOError', I just tested it having one of the files opened. I've been testing this by myself but I can't get the same error. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Basically, it wrote a file with .xlsx file extension, when I try to open it with excel there is a warning window telling me the file is invalid, and when I open it with a simple text editor, there is nothing, is totally blank.

Comment: `ExcelWriter` support Python's `with` syntax.  You should use the `with` syntax since it will always guarantee the file is properly written and closed.

Comment: If you don't close a file before quitting, you _do not_ get an `IOError` in python. That must be a different issue.

Comment: The file may look "totally blank" in a text editor, but that doesn't mean much: It may still contain nulls and all sorts of other things. Find out its true size from Explorer (or with DIR from the CMD prompt), or whatever.

Comment: @alexis Hi, thank you again for the comments, well, there are different things, the only error I get when I open one of those files is IOError, and if I try again after closing them there is no problem, everything works fine, and the totally blank file makes me feel afraid of this error because when I open other excel files in the text editor I can see some content, like this: PK    æVGÞíìa  Ë     xl/worksheets/sheet1.xmlUK›0¾÷WX¾7æÈ&"¬’Ð

Comment: What you're saying is not evidence that my guess is wrong. Check that your code always closes all files, and/or protect it by always using the `with` statement as @TheBlackCat suggested.